# Using namespace in path range query

Tags: javascript, marklogic, marklogic-8

I am using [cts.pathRangeQuery](https://docs.marklogic.com/cts.pathRangeQuery) on an xml document like -

```
<container xmlns:c="http://example.com/ns/core" xmlns:d="http://example.com/ns/data" xmlns="http://example.com/ns/core">
  <c:domain>
    <d:id>http://example.com/xyz/no-data</d:id>
  </c:domain>
</container>
```

I want to use a path range query on `/c:domain/d:id`, something like this -

```
cts.pathRangeQuery("/c:domain/d:id", "=", "some-id");
```

But I don't know how to take care of the XML namespaces in this case. Any suggestions on how to do this in JavaScript?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will want to define your namespaces on the Http Server. See http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/admin/namespaces for more details.

[image: Defining namespaces on an Http Server]

Comment: Some functions (like [xpath](http://docs.marklogic.com/Document.xpath)) allow you specify bindings, but cts.pathRangeIndex isn't one. There is also a [string representation for QNames](http://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp.keyFromQName), but it looks like that's just for map keys.

Comment: You can manage the namespaces using the [Configuration portion of the Management API](http://docs.marklogic.com/REST/client/configuration).